# Gradle Command from configurations.compile.collect

Tags: gradle

I stumbled upon one article about how to make fat jar files in Gradle.

```
jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

My questions are

1. what is the jar element? Is it a way to declare properties. As I understand, I can define properties as follows:

   prop1{
      prop2{
         prop3.prop4=5
      }
   }

which is equivalent to: prop1.prop2.prop3.prop4=5

2. the from statement: Is it a method? I mean is it from (params).

I also found an article about ConfigurationContainer: https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html.

However, I can't link the information to make a full picture here.

Answer (score 26):

1. [`jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:jar) is a task name. It has nothing to do with properties. [Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html) are the basic building block of every Gradle build. It is equivalent to `tasks.jar`
2. `from` is a method of the [`CopySpec`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html) class. Many tasks extend from the `CopySpec` class and inherit the `from` method.

`configurations.compile` is a reference to the all of the artifacts defined in the `compile` [configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#defineConfiguration).

[`.collect {}`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/05/groovy-goodness-use-collect-with.html) is a method call with one argument that is a [closure](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html). `{}` is an empty closure.

`{ it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }` is the closure (aka function) that returns a collection of files to be include in the JAR. `it` is the default argument of every closure that in the case, will be a JAR artifact instance from `configurations.compile` or a local file path instance. It could be a file path because `configurations` support both JARS and local files system paths of compiled `.class` files.

The logic in the closure is in the form of `<conditional> ? <A> : <B>` and means `if <conditional> then return <A> else return <B>`.

The conditional `it.isDirectory()` evaluates to `True` if the `it` variable is a directory. So if `it` is a directory we return `it`. If it's not a directory, then the code assumes it's a JAR.

[`zipTree(it)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#zipTree(java.lang.Object)) is a method that extracts all the files from a JAR and returns them as a collection.

All of the file (directories or exploded JARS) are returned from the closure and then "combined" by `collect` into a single collection (e.g. `FileTree`).

Comment: for more info about the _jar_ task (and the _from_ method), check:  https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html.

Comment: @Amnon Exactly what type of code snippet are you looking for? The question provided the code snipped and is asking what each part represents. If you have different questions about this code snippet you could either open a new question, or politely ask for the detail in the answer comment.